# Realm on react-native : can't get results when not debugging

Tags: android, react-native, realm, realm-js

I can't get the results of any query when **not debugging**, but works perfectly when **debugging**

Also I noticed that Realm is behaving very differently according to wither debugging or not

This is just a summary of the idea :

I'm printing `object.constructor.name` to find the type of the object

**When debugging (Remotely using Chrome or Safari) :**

```
let realm = new Realm(config);
realm.constructor.name --> will print (Realm)

let dogs = realm2.objects('Dog');
dogs.constructor.name --> will print (Results)

(inserting few dogs)

for (let oneDog of dogs) {
    oneDog.constructor.name --> will print (RealmObject)
} --> works perfectly
```

**But when not debugging everything is different:**

```
let realm = new Realm(config);
realm.constructor.name --> will print (Object)

let dogs = realm2.objects('Dog');
dogs.constructor.name --> will print nothing

(inserting few dogs)

for (let oneDog of dogs) {
    oneDog.constructor.name --> not compiled
} --> will give the error below
```

[image]

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating ‘_iterator[typeof
Symbol === “function” ? Symbol.iterator : “@@iterator”]()')
```

I'm not sure if it's a bug or a problem with my codes

---

### Version of Realm and Tooling

- Realm JS SDK Version: 2.10.0
- React Native: 0.55.4
- Client OS & Version: Running on Android device 8.0
- Which debugger for React Native: Chrome

---

### Full code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Realm = require('realm');

export default class Page3Screen extends Component {
  state = { messege : 'no messege' }

  componentWillMount() {
    const config = {
      schema: [{ name: 'Dog', properties: { name: 'string' } }],
    };
    let realm = new Realm(config);
    console.log(realm.constructor.name);
    this.setState({ messege: realm.constructor.name });

    realm.write(() => {
      realm.create('Dog', { name: 'Zozo' });
    });

    let dogs = realm.objects('Dog');
    // console.log(dogs.constructor.name);
    // this.setState({ messege: dogs.constructor.name });

    // for (let oneDog of dogs) {
    //    console.log(oneDog.constructor.name);
    //    this.setState({ messege: oneDog.constructor.name });
    // }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{this.state.messege}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15902)

> For whatever reason react-native on android is shipping an old as shit
>   version of JSC, one that doesn't have support for language features
>   that current react version needs to work

it was solved by [updating the JSC version that ships with android](https://github.com/react-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#how-to-use-it-with-my-react-native-app), but I've used JSC version **216113** instead of the latest to keep **minSdkVersion 17** instead of **21**

Here are the instructions:

````
Follow steps below in order for your React Native app to use new version of JSC VM on android:

1. Add `jsc-android` to the "dependencies" section in your `package.json`:
```
dependencies {
+  "jsc-android": "^216113.0.0",
```

then run `npm install` or `yarn` (depending which npm client you use) in order for the new dependency to be installed in `node_modules`

2. Modify `andorid/build.gradle` file to add new local maven repository packaged in the `jsc-android` package to the search path:
```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
+       maven {
+           // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC library built for Android
+           url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/android"
+       }
    }
}
```

3. Update your app's `build.gradle` file located in `android/app/build.gradle` to force app builds to use new version of the JSC library as opposed to the version specified in [react-native gradle module as a dependency](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e8df8d9fd579ff14224cacdb816f9ff07eef978d/ReactAndroid/build.gradle#L289):

```
}

+configurations.all {
+    resolutionStrategy {
+        force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
+    }
+}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
```

4. You're done, rebuild your app and enjoy updated version of JSC on android!
````

Comment: thank you morteza for sharing your knowledge, I've never faced with your issue but if I do I'll remember your solution. tnx

Answer (score 0):

when you are in `debugging` mode, react-native runs js code inside your browser instead of the device.
since you say it works fine on browser but breaks on device, I suggest you check the following:

- check if device is connected to the same network
- run this : `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
- check if dev server is running or not, you can run it with: `$ react-native start`
- some of the JS features need polyfill in react-native such as `Symbol`. so add the following to `index.js`:

  ```
  import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
  import 'core-js/fn/symbol/iterator';
  ```
- in very very rare situations you have differences between JS engine on browser and android/ios device

good luck.

Comment: I think based on your own answer that you got that rare situation, since you were complaining about old version of Javascript Core. @MujtabaFR